# Jquery Mobile. Click events

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need that on every page change or on some elemetents (a, input[button, submit], data-role=button) click event show loading message. I tried this piece of code:

```
$(document).live(`pagebeforehide`, function(){
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    //More stuff to do
});
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can set this up in the Global Configs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

> **loadingMessage string, default: "loading"** 
>   
> Set the text that appears when a page is loading. If set to false, the message will not
>   appear at all. 
>   **loadingMessageTextVisible boolean, default: false** 
>   
> Whether the text should be visible when a loading message is shown. The text is always
>   visible for loading errors.

And here is the docs for $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg method

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html

Here is an example of using the loading message/spinner with a click event

- http://jsfiddle.net/J8nYh/

JS

```
$("input, a:jqmData(clickload='show')").on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked show');
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "This is only a test", true);
});

$("input, a:jqmData(clickload='spin')").on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked spin');
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "This is only a test", false);
});

$("input, a:jqmData(clickload='hide')").on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked hide');
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <a href="#" id="showMe" data-role="button" data-clickload="show">Show Loading Message</a>
    <a href="#" id="showMe" data-role="button" data-clickload="spin">Show Loading Spinner</a>
    <a href="#" id="hideMe" data-role="button" data-clickload="hide">Hide Loading Message/Spinner</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/vDTVw/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/vDTVw/8/) ?

Comment: @PhillPaffford i inserted your code sample in the header, so than my jqm app fully loads i have ul list of links and when i click the item - messege appears, page changes and message hides. Thats OK. In next page there is  ul list of links too and in the header there is a link too. All links have attribute `data-clickload="show"` but when i click one of these no loading message appears.

Comment: try replacing this .on() with .live()

Comment: Yeap. Now it is much better - it works. Many thanks @PhillPafford. You saved my week. :)

Comment: However loading message on click and hiding on pageshow events is very  unpredictable. Sometimes _button_ or _link_ click event (show message) fires right after _pageshow_ event (hide message). Sotimes loading message even do not appear though in console log prompted message that  execution entered in function there is `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("e", "Palaukite...", true);` code line. I'll try make an exmample of kind stuff in jsfiddle.